# in_app_purchase flutter how to know if subscription was cancel

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have implemented subscription successfully, it is working fine. Now I want to know if a user has cancelled their subscription, I know that the cancellation is manage directly by apple, but what function to use from in_app_purchase to get this info. I have read that using _listenToPurchaseUpdated method you can get the data but, that is called during the subscription process, How can I get that data during users Login, in order to remove the subscription features in case the subscription was cancelled.
Thank you